Functions exported from Kinde Authentication not working
I am using Kinde Authentication within my Next.js Application. I am using a App router for my Next.js app. When I try to use the useKindeBrowserClient function provided by Kinde, it says
TypeError: (0 , _kinde_oss_kinde_auth_nextjs___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.useKindeBrowserClient) is not a function

Below is my Header.jsx file :
"use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover";
import MyDropdownMenu from "./MyDropdownMenu";
import {RegisterLink, LoginLink} from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/";
import {useKindeBrowserClient} from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs";


const Header = () => {
  const Menu = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Home",
      path: "/",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Explore",
      path: "/explore",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Contact Us",
      path: "#contactus",
    },
  ];

  const {user, getUser} = useKindeBrowserClient();
  const alsoUser = getUser();
  
  console.log(user);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center p-2 shadow-sm">
      <div className="flex items-center gap-10 ">
        <Link href="/">
          <Image src="/logo.svg" width={200} height={100} alt="logo" />
        </Link>

        <ul className="hidden md:flex gap-8 ">
          {Menu.map((item) => (
            <Link key={item.id} href={item.path}>
              <li className="hover:text-primary cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 transition-all ease-in-out">
                {item.name}
              </li>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-center content-center my-auto">
        {user ? (
          <Popover>
            <PopoverTrigger>
              <Image
                src={user?.picture || "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_1280.png"}
                alt="profile-image"
                width={40}
                height={40}
                className="rounded-full"
              />
            </PopoverTrigger>
            <PopoverContent className="w-44">
              <ul className="flex flex-col gap-2">
                <Link href="/my-booking" className="cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-md">
                  My Booking
                </Link>
                <li className="cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-100 p-2 rounded-md">
                  {/* Uncomment and import LogoutLink properly */}
                  {/* <LogoutLink> Logout </LogoutLink> */}
                  <span>Logout</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </PopoverContent>
          </Popover>
        ) : (
          <>
          <LoginLink>Sign in</LoginLink>
          <RegisterLink>Sign up</RegisterLink>
          </>
        )}
        <ul className="block md:hidden ml-5 my-auto">
          <MyDropdownMenu />
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;


The Error is : Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: (0 , _kinde_oss_kinde_auth_nextjs___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.useKindeBrowserClient) is not a function

I am following this doc : https://docs.kinde.com/developer-tools/sdks/backend/nextjs-sdk/
